# How to get desktop path from windows service?

Tags: qt, c++11, windows-services

I have windows service which is written on Qt. How to get desktop path for current user?

Comment: QStandardPaths did not work

Comment: define _did not work_.

Comment: _Which_ current user? A service cannot assume there exists exactly one current user.

Comment: Agreed with @MSalters. Getting the desktop path of the current user in a service does not make sense. I'd guess that you have a bad design of your service. Maybe you can tell a bit more about what  you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) will give you standart paths for system and current user.

But don't forget what your service are running under system user by default and not under your local user profile if you didn't set it so. Just check it in `services.msc`  On the second tab in your service preferences you can also change the user under which your service will be executed.

[image]

EDIT: Also you can use standard [MSDN API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) to get system and user paths. This code for example will give you Documents folder for current user under which the service is running. With [fromWCharArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromWCharArray) you can convert it then to [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)

```
#include "Shlobj.h"
    QString path;
    wchar_t* localAppData = nullptr;
        if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, nullptr, &localAppData) == S_OK)
        {
            path = QString::fromWCharArray(localAppData);
            CoTaskMemFree(reinterpret_cast<void*>(localAppData));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Services do have limited access. usually they can't access anything desktop-related. Qt is supposed to be used for desktop apps.

Linux daemon and windows service are completely different in principle of function. Windows maintains life cycle of  a service and there are service-specific subsystems in API. Linux daemon is just another process running in background, nothing  special in comparison to other processes otherwise.

Services run under system account, network account or some superuser account, with no access to desktop function. Services not meant to interact with *current* logged-in user, it's background  processes for interaction with OS and hardware (drivers are kind of service too).

It is possible to enable access to current user but such is a security risk and involves Windows API, as well as action to be taken to configure service. Running service as local user that got a profile is a security risk too.

Usual setup is to create service and GUI app that interacts with that service and runs under current user.

Services use different entry points from standard application, just like windows .dll got its own entry points.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9(v=vs.100).aspx

Complete example of service:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476(v=vs.85).aspx

There was component called QtService, but it is no longer maintained, probably because of security changes. Unless  service support for Qt as project type would be added, at best it would be not a fully functional service.

Comment: That's wrong. Windows services are just standard executables. The only difference is that they must react to start/stop/pause/resume messages from the OS. It does not need any particular new project type. And indeed QtService is available (as part of QtSolutions), and it does just that: abstracting the service to service manager communication.

Comment: Mostly correct. While @BenjaminT is correct in stating that they are technically PE executables (i.e. not DLL's), the fundamental part of this answer is that services are mostly independent from the current user. More importantly, services almost always run under a different user account.

Comment: Also I do not really see the difference between Unix and Windows services. In both cases you have a process that runs in the background and communicate with a service manager to report its state. The fact that Windows provides its own service manager and that Linux lets you choose the one you want (systemd or whatever) does not make a big difference.

Comment: @MSalters bit DLLs are PE executables. With DLLMain exported entry point. ServiceMain  is entry point for a service. Difference between execution process  is that main function of windows service ..exits and terminates its thread (only similarity with daemon), but it registers itself with  Service Control Manager.  Service Control Manager calls back directly  into  service module, or spawns a process that calls, just like a program calls into a .dll, e.g. calling exported StartService function to start the service. This explains why some standard OS services are .dll files not .exe files.

Comment: @Benjamin T QtService code had last major update 5 years ago, with minor bugfixes later (not late than a year ago) and those aren't really part of Qt library, until that it had major problems with service life cycle (e.g. service life was tied to desktop user session, it terminated on logoff, that was addressed one of recent fixes). I'm not even sure that it works with Qt5. Works with Qt4, I tentatively used it (my company code base restricted to Qt4.x)

Comment: @Swift Qt Service works fine with Qt 5. It is available and it works, it don't see why people shouldn't use it.   And what's your point with the 5 years without major update? Some big part of Qt also didn't get any major update for some years.

Comment: @Benjamin T My concern is that Microsoft side was reworked/updated since 2011 (and inner working of QtService seemed to be based on 2011 SDK documentation). We didnt used qt5 becase QTcpServer didn't work with QtService on linux  ( bug was fixed later, apparently, but there are plenty of others)